# InMemoryUser.Subject Usage

Tags: identityserver3

I'm playing around with IdentityServer3 and I've not been able to find any documentation on what the `Subject` property on the `InMemoryUser` object is for.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of some documentation or explain it if it's straight forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer on <strike>[this web page](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/simplestOAuth.html)</strike> (link no longer active).  The web page stated:

> Username and Password are used to authenticate the user, the Subject
>   is the unique identifier for that user that will be embedded into the
>   access token.

Comment: The link throws 404. It seems not available now.